# Rails validation error display issue with embedded form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a "projects/show" page for that shows the details of the selected project. Within the show page I have a simple form so that someone can enter updates and comments on a given project. Everything seems to be working but for some reason I cannot get validation working for the form.

I guess I should say that the validation works because the comment is not created, but the error message does not display. Here is gist link to my code:

[Gist Link](https://gist.github.com/spacerobotTR/a7a926559288948db864ffe805b1735f)

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem #1**

On this line:

```
<%= form_for([@project, @project.comments.build]) do |f| %>
```

...you are building a brand new comment every time, regardless of whether this is the initial invocation of the form, or after an invalid submission. This new comment does not have the errors of `@comment`.

Try this instead:

```
<%= form_for([@project, @comment || @project.comments.build]) do |f| %>
```

In the `new` action, `@comment` will be `nil`, so a new comment will be built. In the `create` action, `@comment` is present already, so it will be used to display the errors and repopulate the form.

Alternative (perhaps cleaner) solution:

```
# in the controller
def new
  @comment = @project.comments.build
end

# in the template
<%= form_for([@project, @comment]) do |f| %>
```

---

**Problem #2**

You always redirect away from the `create` action, even if there is an error. Instead, you can just re-render the `show` template again:

```
if @comment.save
  redirect_to project_path(@project), notice: 'Comment was successfully created.'
else
  render "projects/show"
end
```

Comment: They're also redirecting away from comments#create in all cases (even on the error) so they'll need to `render 'project/show'` instead in case of failure. (It looks like all this kicks off in project/show not some comment/new template).

Comment: Hmm... good point, I didn't notice the `else` clause because of the weird indentation. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I have made the changes above and also changed the else to render 'projects/show' but I am getting errors "NoMethodError in Comments#create". I am wondering if I am somehow not getting back to the proper project number I was on?

Comment: What missing method is it complaining about?

Comment: [Screenshot of error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fv7i439cy5z4h4b/railserror.png?dl=0)

Comment: Oh. Just make sure `@comments` is set in the `create` action as well.

Comment: Sorry how/where would I set that exactly?

Comment: The same way you set it in the `show` action of `ProjectsController`. Now that `CommentsController#create` is also rendering `projects/show.html.erb`, it needs to provide all the necessary variables to it (the same ones provided by `ProjectsController#show`.

Comment: Yes! That's it. It is working now. Thanks I appreciate the help.